# Relationship between fragments of the axiom of choice and the dependent choice principles

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, forcing, axiom-of-choice, independence-results

The dependent choice principle ${\rm DC}_\kappa$ states that if $S$ is a nonempty set and  $R$ is a binary relation such that for every $s\in S^{\lt\kappa}$, there is $x\in S$ with $sRx$, then there is a function $f:\kappa\to S$ such that for every $\alpha<\kappa$, $f\upharpoonright\alpha R f(\alpha)$. The axiom of choice fragment ${\rm AC}_\kappa$ states that every family of size $\kappa$ has a choice function. There are several classical theorems (see Jech's "Axiom of Choice", chapter 8) concerning the relationship between the dependent choice principles and fragments of the axiom of choice.

**Theorem 1**: Over  ${\rm ZF}$, ${\rm AC}$ is equivalent to $\forall\kappa\,{\rm DC}_\kappa$.

**Theorem 2**: Over  ${\rm ZF}$, $\forall \kappa\,{\rm AC}_\kappa$ implies ${\rm DC}_\omega$.

**Theorem 3**: It is consistent with  ${\rm ZF}$ that $\forall \kappa\,{\rm AC_\kappa}$ holds but ${\rm DC_{\omega_1}}$ fails (theorem 8.9).

**Theorem 4**: It is consistent with  ${\rm ZF}$ that ${\rm AC}_\kappa$ holds for some cardinal $\kappa>>\omega$ but ${\rm DC}_\omega$ fails (theorem 8.12).

Jech proves theorems 3 and 4 using permutation models (and then discusses how to obtain ${\rm ZF}$-models with the same properties). But I am wondering whether there are direct symmetric model constructions for these two results. Either a reference for the arguments or the arguments themselves would be appreciated.

Comment: The references seem to be interchanged: 3 corresponds to Theorem 8.9 and 4 to Theorem 8.12

Comment: I think that you can do it in a "similar way" by using a Cohen forcing. This is essentially adding sufficiently many Cohen sets, and defining atom-like names (meaning they all have the same properties over the ground model), and use the same type of automorphisms and filters. The argument *should* translate relatively smoothly. I will sit and verify that after I had some sleep. But my experience with translating permutation models to symmetric models says that it has a good chance of working.

Comment: Thanks, Asaf! This is exactly what I dreaded having to do :).

Comment: Well, I have been wanting to sit and do it for two years now. This seems like a good excuse to do it.

Comment: I've just checked Howard-Rubin and it seems that at least for result 3 it can be done as Asaf says; Feferman/Solovay model does the trick. You have to add $\omega_1$ generic reals to the base model without collecting them in a set. For result 4, however, it seems the only available model is Jech's permutation model...

Comment: @godelian: I'm not sure what Feferman/Solovay (which have a fundamental difference between them, seen when repeating the Solovay construction on smaller limit cardinals, see Truss' paper about many perfect sets) has to do with adding $\omega_1$ generic reals without adding the set of the generic reals. In either cases you add collapsing reals, and you add the sets of the reals which do each collapse.

Comment: Oh, I'm referring to the model $\mathcal{M}13$, called in the book "Feferman/Solovay", it's just one model which extends $\mathcal{M}2$, called "Feferman" model there. Are we using different terminology or you meant to say something else?

Comment: @godelian: I have to admit that I never managed to catch up to the whole $\cal Mn$ and so on. I thought that you were talking about Feferman-Levy/Solovay type constructions (which are "same same but different") but it seems that you are talking about something else. If you can give the citation for the construction I'd be grateful (I won't have access to the book until next week).

Comment: Sure, the book refers to page 166 of Felgner, U. "Models of ZF set theory", Springer-Verlag, Berlin. I run into this model from the "Consequences..." web page, where I just searched for something validating form 40 ($\forall \kappa AC_{\kappa}$) but not form 44 ($DC_{\omega_1}$) and that was not a permutation model.

Comment: @godelian: Thanks. I have to admit that my first thought was to look in Felgner, but I just hate the presentations there. I think I'll still sit down to write these things down properly. Thanks!

Comment: @godelian Can you sketch a few details about why the model works? I won't have access to the book for a while also. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ok, I thought about it and I think the symmetric model obtained from adding $\omega_1$-many Cohen reals with coordinate flipping automorphisms works for theorem 3.

Comment: Oh, good, then I won't have to go to the construction myself :) I just had read that it was Solovay who proved result 3 in this model. So now the real challenge is result 4, since the book only mentions permutation models for that.

Comment: Vika, both constructions are quite straightforward. I'm writing something now. I'll see to upload a rudimentary version later tonight (which I will then expand and add some basic introduction to symmetric models, and flesh out the proofs I currently "leave to the reader" [read: to look in my paper/thesis where they can be found].

Comment: I am looking forward to reading it, Asaf!

Comment: Ugh. Unexpected complications. Sometimes forcing is really annoying! :-)

Comment: (Unexpected complications are over; first proof is over, hopefully the second will be done tomorrow. Now it's time to sleep!)

Comment: @godelian, Victoria: I gave up on writing a proper .pdf file, and instead summarized here the re-proofs from Jech as symmetric models.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The idea is to mimic the permutation models as given in Jech. One can then ask, "Well, in Jech he chooses some set of objects in the full universe, and shows it has a support. But in forcing we don't have a simple access to names like that, since they might not be "sufficiently determined" for us to collect them into a symmetric name!"

To counter the effects of this problem here is a generalized formulation of The Continuity Lemma, as Felgner called it (for the basic Cohen model). $\newcommand{\PP}{\Bbb{P}}\newcommand{\dom}{\operatorname{dom}}\newcommand{\fix}{\operatorname{fix}}\newcommand{\sym}{\operatorname{sym}}\newcommand{\forces}{\Vdash}$

> Suppose that $\PP$ is a Cohen type forcing, with $p\colon A\times\kappa\to2$ such that the domain of $p$ is $<\kappa$, ordered by reverse inclusion. We write $s(p)$ as the projection of the $\dom p$ onto $A$.
>
> Let $\scr G$ be a group of permutations of $A$ acting on $\PP$ naturally: $\pi p(\pi a,\alpha)=p(a,\alpha)$. And let $I$ be an ideal on $A$ which is closed under $\scr G$, and $s(p)\in I$ for all $i\in I$. Moreover, assume that whenever $X,Y\in I$ there is a permutation in $\scr G$ such that $\pi\upharpoonright(X\cap Y)=\operatorname{id}$ and $\pi''(X\setminus Y)$ is disjoint from $Y$.
>
> **Then** whenever $\dot x_1,\ldots,\dot x_n$ are symmetric names with respect to the filter generated by $\{\fix(E)\mid E\in I\}$ and $E\in I$ such that $\fix(E)$ is a subgroup of $\sym(\dot x_i)$ for each $i$, and $p\forces^{\sf HS}\varphi(\dot x_1,\ldots,\dot x_n)$ then $p\upharpoonright(E\times\kappa)\forces^{\sf HS}\varphi(\dot x_1,\ldots,\dot x_n)$.

(If you are uncomfortable with the notion of $\forces^{\sf HS}$ you can instead require $\varphi$ to be $\Delta_0$, and replace the relativized quantifiers by names one at a time.)

Okay let me explain this for a second, since there are plenty of conditions and plenty of more conditions in the consequences. The idea is that if $p$ forces that something happens in the symmetric model, about concrete symmetric names, then we can restrict $p$ to something whose support is in the ideal, and already this decides the same value for the same statement with the same names. In our two examples, all the conditions will be easy to verify.

---

### Theorem I:

> Let $\kappa$ be a regular cardinal, then it is consistent that $\sf DC_\kappa$ holds, $\sf W_{\kappa^+}$ fails, and $(\forall \lambda\in\rm Ord)\sf AC_\lambda$

#### Proof.

We take $\PP$ to be functions from $\kappa^+\times\kappa\to2$ with domain smaller than $\kappa$. $\scr G$ here is the group of all permutations of $\kappa^+$ and $I$ is $[\kappa^+]^{\leq\kappa}$. So the conditions easily hold, and just to remind you here our filter of subgroups is the one generated by $\{\fix(E)\mid E\in I\}$, and it is normal since $I$ is closed under the operation of $\scr G$, and $\cal F$ is $\kappa^+$-complete since $I$ is $\kappa^+$-complete.

If $G$ is a generic filter, we let $a_\alpha=\{\beta\mid\exists p\in G: p(\alpha,\beta)=1\}$, and $\dot a_\alpha$ is going to be the canonical name for this set. Additionally, $A$ is the set of all these $a_\alpha$ and $\dot A$ will be its canonical name. Let $N$ be a symmetric model defined by $\cal F$ given above, then by standard arguments $A$ is in $N$.

First off, if both the forcing is $\kappa^+$-c.c. and the filter is $\kappa^+$-complete, then $\sf DC_\kappa$ holds in the symmetric model, and this is the case here assuming suitable $\sf GCH$. This much is easy to verify (see my paper ["Preserving Dependent Choice"](https://dx.doi.org/10.4064/ba8169-12-2018) for that). So we have this for almost free.

Secondly, $\sf W_{\kappa^+}$ fails since $|A|$ and $\kappa^+$ are incomparable. This is a standard proof, like the one in Cohen's first model with the Dedekind-finite set of real numbers.

The big trick is to show that given a function $X\colon\lambda\to N\setminus\{\varnothing\}$ then we want to find a function $g$ with domain $\lambda$ such that $g(i)\in X(i)$. Suppose that $p\in G$ and $\dot X$ is a hereditarily symmetric name for $X$ such that $p$ forces $\dot X$ has the above properties.

Let $E\in I$ be a support for $\dot X$, namely if $\pi\in\fix(E)$ then $\pi\dot X=\dot X$. Without loss of generality $s(p)\subseteq E$ and $|E|=\kappa$. Pick some $E'$ disjoint to $E$ and $|E'|=|E|$. We will find a choice function with support $E\cup E'$.

For each $\alpha<\lambda$, find a maximal antichain below $p$, $D=\{q_\gamma\mid\gamma<\kappa\}$, such that there is a hereditarily symmetric name $\dot y_\gamma$ for which $q_\gamma\forces\dot y_\gamma\in\dot X(\check\alpha)$. Let $E_\gamma$ be such that $s(q_\gamma)\subseteq E_\gamma$ and $\fix(E_\gamma)\subseteq\sym(\dot y_\gamma)$.

Now, find $\pi\in\fix(E)$ such that $\pi\colon\bigcup_{\gamma<\kappa}E_\gamma\to E\cup E'$ (it need not be surjective between the two sets, just a permutation of $\kappa^+$ mapping the points outside of $E$ into $E'$). Note that $\{\pi q_\gamma\mid\gamma<\kappa\}$ remain a maximal antichain below $p$. But now, $\sym(\pi\dot y_\gamma)$ contains $\fix(E\cup E')$.

Finally, let $\dot x_\alpha$ denote the name mixed over the $\pi q_\gamma$ from the $\pi\dot y_\gamma$. Namely, $\pi q_\gamma\forces\dot x_\alpha=\pi\dot y_\gamma$. This can be done in a way that ensures that $\dot x_\alpha$ is hereditarily symmetric, since all the $\pi\dot y_\gamma$ and the $\pi q_\gamma$ have a common support, namely $E\cup E'$.

Now define $\dot g=\{(p,(\check\alpha,\dot x_\alpha)^\bullet)\mid\alpha<\lambda\}$, and it is easy to see that $p\forces\dot g(\check\alpha)\in\dot X(\check\alpha)$ and that $\dot g$ is hereditarily symmetric as wanted. $\square$

---

### Theorem II:

> If $\kappa$ is uncountable, then it is consistent that $\sf DC$ fails, $\sf W_{<\kappa}$ and $\sf AC_{<\kappa}$ both hold.

### Proof.

Let me skimp out on most of the details. We take $A$ in this case to be $\kappa^{<\omega}$ (you can replace $\omega$ here by the least cardinal for which you want $\sf DC$ to fail). Our automorphism group is going to be the automorphisms of the tree $\kappa^{<\omega}$ and the ideal of supports is the ideal of subtrees of cardinality less than $\kappa$ with no branches (in the case of $\sf DC$ these are really the subtrees which are well-founded).

For $t\in\kappa^{<\omega}$ define $a_t$ as the Cohen set defined when fixing $t$ and $A$ as the set of all $a_t$'s. Then the structure of $\kappa^{<\omega}$ is fixed trivially by the automorphisms, so $A$ has a tree structure but no branches (since a branch would require a support with an unbounded tree). Therefore $\sf DC$ fails.

To show that $\sf W_\lambda$ or $\sf AC_\lambda$ hold, for $\lambda<\kappa$, we perform a trick similar to the previous proof. However here we need to be slightly more careful. But we can also notice that the union of trees whose intersection is without branches is also without branches. Therefore the union of any less than $\kappa$ "almost disjoint" supports is a support.

So here we take a name and by induction we construct a sequence of conditions and names which witness $\sf W_\lambda$ or $\sf AC_\lambda$. Simply by ensuring that the next name we take has a support which extends the previously chosen names "sideways" and not "up". This will guarantee that the union of the symmetric names for the functions at limit steps is a function. And again the generalized continuity lemma ensures we can always restrict back to smaller conditions as we progress, to ensure that their support is in the ideal.

Comment: Yes, maybe I went a bit too far with the length of this answer... :-)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, Asaf! I am going to try to work out the details of the second proof.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Please add the definition of $\mathsf W_\kappa$ to your answer.

Comment: @Taras: That's from Jech's book. It states "Every cardinal is comparable with $\kappa$", that is to say, if a set does not inject into $\kappa$, then $\kappa$ injects into that set.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you, but anyway, it is better to have all notions appearing in formulations of theorem defined, just for convenience of readers. Unfortunately I do not have Jech's book on Axioms of Chice (only his funcdamental "Set Theory").

Comment: @AsafKaragila Dear Asaf, on stachexchange I found your very helpful answer (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/211621) in which you mention that the Ultrafilter Lemma implies the existence of a linear order on each set. Could you give me a reference to this fact or a hint how it can be proved? Thank you.

Comment: @Taras: You can find the proof in Jech's "Axiom of Choice", I am sure. Here are two ways to prove it. (1) The Ultrafilter Lemma is equivalent to the compactness theorem for FOL, given a set $A$, look at the language of $\{<,c_a\}_{a\in A}$ and the axioms stating that $<$ is linear and that each $c_a$ is distinct from the others, easily compactness apply here and we have a model. (2) We show the Order Extension Property (then apply it to the discrete order), and you can find a proof of that in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/271012/622 if you want a "proper cite-able reference", let me know.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you for the prompt answer. At the moment it suffices for my purposes (I mean no need for "proper cite-able reference"). Anyway, the proof is not so elementary (somehow it escaped from me).

Comment: @Taras: Not very elementary indeed. The one with the compactness theorem is much easier. But the proof of that equivalence is not trivial in itself, so it's not a good substitute if you don't have it in the bag already.

Comment: @AsafKaragila By the way, do you the name for the statement "The union of a countable family of countable sets is countable", denoted by $AC^\omega_\omega$? Is this notation standard? By the "name" I mean something like "Countable Axiom fo Choice" because the "Axiom of Countable Choice" is already occupied: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_countable_choice

Comment: @Taras: That is known as the Countable Union Theorem, denoted by CUT. What you're writing is "choice from countable families of countable sets", which is not strong enough to prove the CUT.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Aha, then $AC^\omega_\omega$ is another weakening between $CUT$ and $AC^{<\omega}_\omega$? By $AC^{<\omega}_\omega$ I means the existence of a choice function for countable families of finite sets. It follows from the existence of linear orders (as you wrote in your post on stackexchange).

Comment: @Taras: Yes. That is correct. $\sf DC\to AC_\omega\to CUT\to AC_\omega^{fin}$, and none of the implications are reversible. Note that some authors switch the subscript and superscript in the notation. But I prefer this way.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you for the expert consultation. It was very helpful (at the moment I am writing a textbook for students and wanted to include some known info on versions of AC).

Comment: @Taras: If you'd like, send me the chapter, I can give you more feedback.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I post the current version to https://www.researchgate.net/publication/340899536_CLASSICAL_SET_THEORY_THEORY_OF_SETS_AND_CLASSES At the moment the section about Choice is absent but maybe today or tomorrow I will finish writing it and will update the text.

Comment: @Taras: Okay, thanks.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Dear Asaf, please look at the update at https://www.researchgate.net/publication/340899536_CLASSICAL_SET_THEORY_THEORY_OF_SETS_AND_CLASSES Now it contains two (last) chapters devoted to Choice and Global Choice. I would appreciate any comments especially concerning the Clobal Choice. Thank you.

Comment: @Taras: I sent you an email with some remarks. Sometimes the emails I send end up in spam folders (it's quite tragic, really, some students missed important announcements because of that in the past).

Comment: @AsafKaragila I read the proof of Theorem 1 and I'm wondering: why is every generic filter intersecting $D_\gamma$ (for each $\gamma$)? You defined $D_\gamma$ to be a maximal antichain of certain conditions $q$ with $s(q)\subseteq E\cup E'$ below some $p\in G$ with $s(p)\subseteq E$... why couldn't we have a condition $p\in G$ such that $s(p)\subseteq E\cup E'$ and $p$ forces $\dot{X}$ has the wanted properties but such that $p$ is incompatible with every condition in $D_\gamma$? Thanks

Comment: in other words: who says that the set $\{q \in \mathbb{P} \mid  s(q)\subseteq E\cup E' \text{ and } \exists \dot{x}_\gamma \ q \Vdash \dot{x}_\gamma \in \dot{X}(\check{\gamma}) \text{ with supp}(\dot{x}_\gamma) \subseteq E\cup E'\}$ is dense below p (forcing that $\dot{X}$ has the wanted properties)?

Comment: @Lorenzo: We effectively showed that given any $p$, there will be some extension which has these desired properties. And so, we effectively show that this set is dense below $p$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila mmm didnt' we show that given any $p$ such that $s(p)\subseteq E$ (and which forces etc.) then there exists a $q\le p$ with etc. ? A priori this is not saying that the set of such $q$s is dense below $p$, because there are a lot of conditions $p'$ below $p$ such that $s(p')\not\subseteq E$, and our argument is not considering them (i.e. a priori we cannot find such conditions $q$ below this $p'$)

Comment: @Lorenzo: But homogeneity plays a bit role here, so we can always assume that $s(p)=E$, since homogeneity tells us that if $p$ forced something "reasonable" about $\dot X$, then $p\restriction E$ already forced that.

Comment: Ok, but in order to prove that the set of $q$s is dense below $p$, we need to prove that given *any* $p'\le p$ we can find a condition $q$ below $p'$... With your argument we can show that there exists a condition $q$ below $p'\upharpoonright E$ (which forces the same as $p'$ by homogeneity) but still this $q$ may not be below $p'$...

Comment: Indeed, maybe I'm wrong, but reading Jech's proof of this result, specifically the transfer argument he sketches, he uses a more complicated automorphism group than the one we are using, and it seems to me that it is necessary to take care of precisely this point..

Comment: @Lorenzo: Transfer theorems tend to be more complicated than necessary, since they are trying to preserve some "additional structure". If you look at the proof of the Jech–Sochor theorem, they effectively embed an entire initial segment of the permutation model into $\kappa$-Cohen generics for a suitably chosen $\kappa$. We don't have that obligation, and we don't care about that. You can also open my paper about realizability results via classical methods, which extends the proof given here to a more general context.

Comment: @Lorenzo: The point being that in order to get something that "feels" like atoms, one has to begin with sets of sets of Cohen generics, rather than just a set of Cohen generics. And by that virtue alone, everything gets more complicated. When trying to just emulate the original proof via forcing, some arguments get simpler, and some arguments get harder, but the model, as a whole, tends to be simpler in that sense.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, what I meant was the automorphism is more complicated even taking into consideration what you just wrote

Comment: Because he uses it to prove that the set of $q$s is dense below $p$, after one encodes his argument into ours.. More precisely it seems that he actually proves that $q$ and $\pi q$ (I'm referring to your proof) are compatible

Comment: @Lorenzo: And that is something you want to do when you want to have atom-like things. We don't need that here. As I keep saying.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry if I'm being repetitive, the point is that I'm not entirely convinced that we've showed that the set of $q$s is dense below $p$, for the reasons I gave briefly 7 comments above. I'll work on it, thanks again!

Comment: @AsafKaragila I think that $\text{AC}_{\kappa}$ actually fails in the symmetric model defined in your proof of Theorem I: to see it consider in $N$ the family $\mathcal{B} = \{[\beta] \mid \beta \in \kappa\}$ with $[\beta] = \{a_\alpha \mid \beta \in a_\alpha\}$. Let $\dot{[\beta]},\dot{\mathcal{B}}$ be their canonical names and note that, for each $\beta$, $1_{\mathbb{P}}\Vdash \dot{[\beta]}\neq \emptyset$. Suppose that there is a condition $p \in G$ and a symmetric name $\dot{f}$ such that $p\Vdash ``\dot{f}: \check{\kappa} \rightarrow \dot{A}$ is a choice function for $\dot{\mathcal{B}}$''.

Comment: Let $E\in I$ be the support for $\dot{f}$ and assume wlog that $s(p)\subseteq E$. As $|E| < \kappa$  there exists $\gamma \in \kappa$ such that $(\kappa \times \{\gamma\}) \cap \text{dom}(p) = \emptyset$, fix one and let $p' = 
p \cup \{((\alpha, \gamma), 0) \mid \alpha \in E\}$.
Clearly $p' \le p$, assume now that $\exists q \le p', \beta \in \kappa$ and $\alpha\in \kappa\setminus E$ such that $q\Vdash \dot{f}(\check{\beta}) = \dot{a_\alpha}$, this would be a contradiction  (for the same reason $W_\kappa$ fails)

Comment: hence there is none and if we let $\dot{A}_E$ be the canonical name for the set $\{a_\alpha \mid \alpha \in E\}$ then $p' \Vdash \text{ran}(\dot{f}) \subseteq \dot{A}_E$.
But then $p'$ would force $\text{ran}(\dot{f}) \cap \dot{[\gamma]} = \emptyset$, contradiction. Hence in $N$ there is no choice function for $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: @Lorenzo: I think you're right, but I have quite a lot on my head over the next few days so I'll have to try and check this only in a bit. Regardless of that, this can be easily solved by adding $\kappa^+$ subsets to $\kappa$ and taking supports of size $\kappa$; this will give us $\sf DC_\kappa$, rather than $\sf DC{<\kappa}$, but we already agreed that we are dealing with a successor cardinal. Again, I will need to think about it and it will take a few days. But thanks again for the tenacity.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Could you give a look at the answer I posted when you find the time? Thanks!

Comment: @Lorenzo: Yes, that looks fine. I came back today from the conference and tomorrow I'll have the time to fix my answer.

Answer (score 3):

In the comments of Asaf' answer I explain why there is a problem in his proof of Theorem 1. In this answer I try to correct them by slightly modifying his argument. I'll keep the same notation of his answer.

---

### Theorem I

> Let $\kappa$ be a successor cardinal, then it is consistent that $\text{DC}_{<\kappa}$ holds, $\text{W}_\kappa$ fails and $(\forall \lambda \in \text{Ord})\  \text{AC}_\lambda$ holds

### Proof.

Let $\mathbb{P}$, as before, to be the functions from $\kappa\times\kappa \rightarrow 2$ with domain smaller than $\kappa$. If $G$ is a generic filter, $\alpha \in \kappa$ and $s\subset\kappa$ has cardinality less than $\kappa$, we let $$a_{\alpha, s} = \{\beta \mid \exists p \in G : (p(\alpha, \beta) = 1 \text{ and } \beta \not\in s) \text{ or } (p(\alpha, \beta) = 0 \text{ and } \beta \in s)\}$$ with $\dot{a}_{\alpha, s}$ being its canonical name, and for each $\alpha \in \kappa$ we let $$\begin{align*}a_\alpha &= \{a_{\alpha, s} \mid s \subset \kappa \text{ with } |s|<\kappa\}\\A &=\{a_\alpha \mid \alpha\in\kappa\} \end{align*}$$  with $\dot{a}_\alpha, \dot{A}$ being their canonical names.
At this point, for every $X$ subset of $\kappa\times\kappa$, $|X|< \kappa$ we let $\sigma_X$ be the automorphism of $\mathbb{P}$ that interchanges 0's and 1's at every point of $X$, i.e. if $p \in \mathbb{P}$ then $(\sigma_X p) (\alpha, \beta) = 1-p(\alpha, \beta)$ if $(\alpha,\beta) \in X$ and $(\sigma_X p) (\alpha, \beta) = p(\alpha, \beta)$ otherwise.

We let our automorphism group $\cal G$ be generated by $\{\sigma_X \mid X\subset \kappa\times\kappa, |X|<\kappa\}$ and by the group of all permutations of $\kappa$ (the ones in Asaf' answer).
Then we let $\cal F$ be the filter on $\cal G$ generated by $\{\text{fix}(E) \mid E\subset \kappa, |E|<\kappa\}$ with $$\text{fix}(E)=\{\pi \in \mathcal{G} \mid \pi (\dot{a}_{\alpha, s}) = \dot{a}_{\alpha, s} \text{ for all } s \text{ and }\alpha \in E\}$$

Let $N$ be the symmetric model defined by $\cal F$ above, then by standard arguments all $a_{\alpha, s}$'s, all $a_\alpha$'s and $A$ are in $N$.

As before, since both our forcing and our filter are $\kappa$-closed then $\text{DC}_{<\kappa}$ holds in $N$. Moreover $W_\kappa$ fails since $|A|$ and $\kappa$ are incomparable.

Now, regarding $(\forall \lambda \in \text{Ord}) \text{AC}_\lambda$, suppose that we have $X:\lambda \rightarrow N\setminus \{\emptyset\}$ in $N$. Let $\dot{X}$ be a symmetric name for $X$ and let $p \in G$ such that $p$ forces that $\dot{X}$ has the above properties.

Let $E \in [\kappa]^{<\kappa}$ be a support for $\dot{X}$. Pick some $E'$ disjoint from $E$ and such that $|E'|^+ = \kappa$. We will find a choice function with support $E \cup E'$.

First assume that $s(p)\subseteq E\cup E'$. For each $\gamma<\lambda$ let $q\leq p$ such that for some symmetric $\dot y_\gamma$ we have that $q\Vdash\dot y_\gamma\in\dot X(\check\gamma)$. Let $F$ be a support for $\dot y_\gamma$ and assume $s(q) \subseteq F$, now we can find some $\pi\in\text{fix}(E)$ such that $\pi''F\subseteq E\cup E'$ and such that $\pi q$ is compatible with $p$ (first we use a permutation on $\kappa$ that sends $F$ in $E\cup E'$ and then we flip all the eventual bits that would make $p$ and $\pi q$ incompatible).
Define $\dot x_\gamma=\pi\dot y_\gamma$ and let $q'$ extend both $p$ and $\pi q$ with $s(q')\subseteq E\cup E'$, then $q' \le p$ and $q' \Vdash \dot x_\gamma\in\dot X(\check\gamma)$.

So, wrapping up, starting with a condition $p$ with $s(p)\subseteq E \cup E'$ forcing that $\dot{X}$ has the wanted properties and some $\gamma < \lambda$, we have found a symmetric name $\dot x_\gamma$ with support $E\cup E'$ and a condition $q' \le p$ with $s(q')\subseteq E \cup E'$ forcing that $\dot x_\gamma$ is an element of $\dot X(\check \gamma)$.

For each $\gamma<\lambda$ now we can pick a maximal antichain (maximal wrt the functions $q$ with domain in $E\cup E'$) below $p$ of conditions as above, $D_\gamma$ and names $\dot x_\gamma(q)$ as above. Then $\{(q,(\check\gamma,\dot x_\gamma(q))^\bullet)\mid q\in D_\gamma,\gamma<\lambda\}$ is a choice function and $E\cup E'$ is clearly a support for it. $\square$