# Toposes in which countable choice is true but dependent choice isn't

Tags: ct.category-theory, lo.logic, topos-theory, constructive-mathematics

I'd like examples of toposes in which Countable Choice is true but Dependent Choice isn't. I'd prefer examples without Excluded Middle. It's hard to find a natural example.

Comment: Of course this isn't what you want - hence a comment as opposed to an answer - but any (classical) model of ZF+CC+$\neg$DC yields a topos of the appropriate (modulo the logic) type. I suspect that the usual forcing argument for building such models can be adapted to work over an appropriately-picked topos in which CC holds but LEM fails, but this is well outside my zone of competence.

Comment: Well, a classical model is an intuitionistic model as well, so I think Noah's answer counts, and *is* natural.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Yeah, fair enough

Comment: @AndrejBauer I was sort of thinking in the direction of constructive mathematics, but I don't know how to get that across

Comment: I am trying to remember whether I've seen such a model somewhere. It's not going to be a realizaiblity topos, as those always validate dependent choice. Sheaf toposes can violate countable choice pretty easily, but I'm afraid they'll also violate dependent choice. What have you looked at?

Comment: @AndrejBauer I'm not sure whether $\operatorname{Sh}(\mathbb N)$ works. Other than that, I've looked at the same examples as you've listed

Comment: What topology on $\mathbb{N}$ do you have in mind? Sometimes it's possible to take a forcing model and convert it to a Kripke model or some such. What does Jensen's model validating countable choice and invalidating dependent choice look like?

Comment: @AndrejBauer Er, the discrete one?

Comment: @ogogmad that’s just a product of copies of the category of sets, and (thus) satisfies whatever choice principle your category of sets does.

Comment: @Andrej: You add an homogeneous tree of height $\omega$ and preserve countable bounded parts of the tree. This ensures there are no branches, so DC fails, but given a countable set of non-empty sets, we must have that these sets are supported jointly by some bounded set, and utilise this to get a choice function. It's not a simple argument, but that's the idea, if my memory serves me right.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: thanks, it's not that easy to find a reference to this, do you have one? I can find references to Jensen, but then finding the actual paper is harder.

Comment: @Andrej: I will look for it tomorrow. Jech's AC book, Felgner's "Models of ZF set theory", both are good starting points.

Comment: Theorem 8.12 In Jech's "Axiom of Choice", if I'm reading it correctly. It describes a topological group $\mathcal{G}$ such that sets with a continuous $\mathcal{G}$-action give the topos you want.

Comment: @Andrej: https://mathoverflow.net/a/178914/7206 also has a sketch of the details.

Comment: @ogogmad: David Robert's comment is the answer to your question. Is it too terse? I don't really have time to write it out, perhaps someone else can.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Sure

Comment: @DavidRoberts Feel free to post a full answer if you want

Comment: @ogogmad will do.

Comment: @AndrejBauer My aim was to insist on the topos having a constructive internal logic. In that regard, David Roberts's answer is *not* the answer to my question. To resolve this situation, I've asked a separate question. See here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/357212/constructive-toposes-in-which-countable-choice-is-true-but-dependent-choice-isn

Comment: @AndrejBauer I've deleted the question, but somehow I'm not sure if David Roberts has answered the question I actually intended to ask

Comment: What prevents carrying out @DavidRoberts's suggestion over Eff, or whatever constructive topos you like? It's just a sheaf construction after all...

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais Maybe you're right. I'm quite new to this stuff

Comment: I recommend reading Blass and Scedrov, _Freyd's models for the independence of the axiom of choice_.

Comment: Well, then you have to be really clear on what formulations of the choice principles you are wanting, although since CC and DC deal with countable families, it's probably not so much of an issue. Depends on your intended use, I guess.

Answer (score 8):

Given any topological group $G$, the topos of sets with a continuous $G$-action is Boolean, and very often violates some choice principle or other. Under the translation between material and structural set theories, such toposes correspond to permutation (or Fraenkel–Mostowski) models of ZFA.

Theorem 8.12 in Jech's *Axiom of Choice* describes in terms in material sets a model of set theory in which countable choice (i.e. $\mathrm{AC}_{\aleph_0}$) holds, but DC doesn't. [In fact, Jech describes something more general, of which this is the "$<\aleph_1$ case"]

Consider the set $A := \aleph_1^{<\omega} = \bigcup_{n\in \omega} \aleph_1^n$ of finite sequences of countable ordinals. This carries a partial order where $s \leq t$ iff $t$ extends $s$, and is in fact a tree. Consider the automorphism group of this tree, call it $G$. This gets a topology by specifying a filter $F$ generated by an ideal $I\subset P(A)$. A subset $E\subset A$ is in $I$ precisely if it is a countable, bounded-height sub-tree. Then $F$ is the filter generated by the subgroups $\mathrm{Fix}(E) < G$ consisting of automorphisms that fix the subset $E \subset A$ pointwise.

Then the topos of continuous $G$-sets with this topological group is what you wanted.

Comment: I think you've missed a `_0` on that definition of $A$.

Comment: Or rather a `_1`, no?

Comment: Yes, probably that.

Comment: Still weird to see $\aleph_1$ and not $\omega_1$ there, by the way. :)

Comment: Well, I was not particularly aiming for consistency with traditional set-theoretic notation. I've already edited this a bunch of times, you're welcome to change it if you like. I think it would be more nicely expressed in any case if we could write $G$ as the inverse limit of a cofiltered diagram of discrete groups (namely, the quotients of $G$ by subgroups in the filter that are normal), but I'm not quite invested enough to dedicate the time to figure it out.